# Returning Promise from action creator in React Native using redux-thunk

Tags: react-native, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I have an action creator that is called from my React component:

```
// ...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// ...
import { submitProfile } from '../actions/index';

// ...

  onSubmit() {
    const profile = {
      name: this.state.name
      // ...
    };

    this.props.submitProfile(profile)
      .then(() => { // I keep getting an error here saying cannot read property 'then' of undefined...
        console.log("Profile submitted. Redirecting to another scene.");
        this.props.navigator.push({ ... });
      });
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { submitProfile })(MyComponent);
```

The definition of the action creator is something like the following. Note I am using the redux-thunk middleware.

```
export function submitProfile(profile) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post(`some_url`, profile)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Profile submission request was successful!");

        dispatch({ ... }); // dispatch some action

        // this doesn't seem to do anything . . .
        return Promise.resolve();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data.error);
      });
  };
}
```

What I want to be able to do is call the action creator to submit the profile and then after that request was successful, push a new route into the navigator from my component. I just want to be able to determine that the post request was successful so I can push the route; otherwise, I would not push anything, but say an error occurred, try again.

I looked up online and found Promise.resolve(), but it doesn't not seem to solve my problem. I know that I could just do a .then after calling an action creator if I was using the redux-promise middleware. How do I do it with redux-thunk?

Comment: Okay, seems to be working now. I just needed to add the **return** keyword for the axios.post request. That is: return dispatch => { **return** axios.post(...); };

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it. Maybe that will help others with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Actually I did not find the solution because I wanted to handle an error case in the component, when I called the action creator, but it turned out that it always returns a success case, even if in the action creator itself a catch was executed. Maybe I need to return Promise.reject inside the catch block in the action creator in order to make that work?

Comment: You are already handling the promise with your `then` and `catch`. You can dispatch any necessary navigation in your `then`.

Comment: I can't do that because I don't have access to the navigator there. The navigator is passed via props to the component.

Comment: @nbkhope Please post the answer, I am in exact situation. Please post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The return value from the function defined as the thunk will be returned. So the axios request must be returned from the thunk in order for things to work out properly.

```
export function submitProfile(profile) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post(`some_url`, profile) // don't forget the return here
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Profile submission request was successful!");

        dispatch({ ... }); // dispatch some action

        return Promise.resolve();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data.error);
      });
  };
}
```